# can silverlight detect which version of .NET framework installed on client machine?

Tags: .net, silverlight

Can silverlight 3 or silverlight 4 detect which version of .NET framework installed on client machine without being in OOB mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure, just [look at the user-agent header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749404.aspx).

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04425.00).
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can test through silverlight, but you can't count on useragent because you may not find the .net version in the user-agent string. You shall develop an ActiveX component, or an unmanaged app (C++, Delphi, VB6) to detect the installed version (or the version you require), then start downloading your app.

I'm developing an app in which I needed to provide the same functionality as you. So I'm testing through the useragent first (if the user has .NET just download the app). If the .NET is not present in the useragent, then the user download the unmanaged app to test .NET (if there's no .NET 4 installed, it refers you to the download URL).